# Extract specified column contain double quotes using awk

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have an sql dump file, from which I want to extract specified columns. I'm trying to do this using awk.

The problem is some fields contain double quotes ,, so i can't get the match result.

The enclosed character is ','

File include

```
joe','b,,o','fo','d,o','mo
```

The command

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="','"; FS="','" } { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }'
```

note the file at this example has 5 column field but with double quotes.
Thanks in advance

Expected Result with tabs \t

```
joe b,,o fo d,o mo
```

Comment: There is no double quote in `joe','b,,o','fo','d,o','mo` ? What is your expected output?

Comment: @Dr Jay, please post correct input and output in your post and let us know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i've do changement thanks

Comment: When you say "double quotes" do you actually mean "single quotes" or "commas"? There are no double quotes (`"`) in your example, just letters (`a...z`), single quotes (`'`) and commas (`,`). I also don't know what you're trying to tell us with `Expected Result with tabs \t`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```
str="joe','b,,o','fo','d,o','mo"

awk -v OFS='\t' -F "','" '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }' <<< "$str"
```

```
joe    b,,o    fo    d,o    mo
```

Comment: @OP: Did this work out?